# Where is mir/raii.h?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling, mir

I'm trying to compile a program on a Vivid (15.04) Ubuntu Touch device; and the only problem I have is:

```
fatal error: mir/raii.h: No such file or directory
```

The code does:

```
#include "mir/raii.h"
```

... and apparently, that file should have been in the `libmircommon-dev`, which I both have:

```
$ apt-show-versions -r mircommon
libmircommon-dev:armhf/vivid 0.20.3+15.04.20160322-0ubuntu1 uptodate
libmircommon5:armhf/vivid 0.20.3+15.04.20160322-0ubuntu1 uptodate
```

It's definitely not on the system, because I'm doing:

```
sudo find / -xdev -name raii.h
```

... and it returns nothing.

Now, in [Ubuntu – Package Contents Search (trusty) -- raii.h](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=i386&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=raii.h), there is a `/usr/include/mircommon/mir/raii.h` in `mircommon-dev`.

However, already in the next version, [Ubuntu – Package Contents Search (wily) -- raii.h](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&arch=i386&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=raii.h), it is not anymore in `mircommon-dev` - there's just a file `/usr/include/wibble/raii.h` in `libwibble-dev`, which I think is unrelated (and same for all the next versions)

However, I can also see code like [~kdub/mir/key-repeat-gmock-fixes : files for revision 3419](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kdub/mir/key-repeat-gmock-fixes/files), with commits in 2016, which still uses `#include "mir/raii.h"`?

So my question is:

- Is `mir/raii.h` fully removed from Mir, or does it exist in a different package? If so which package should I install?
- If it has been removed completely, what header could I use instead to have the program compile?

---

EDIT: just looked at the apparently latest [mir/development-branch/tarball r.3489](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mir-team/mir/development-branch/tarball/3489?start_revid=3489) (via http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mir-team/mir/development-branch/files), and there is still a

```
./mir/development-branch/src/include/common/mir/raii.h
```

there... the question is then, why isn't it in any of the Ubuntu packages?